# Drupal AJAX checkbox

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, checkbox

When click on checkbox I want to call function checkbox_ajax, I tried but it does not work

```
function checkbox1($form_state) {
    $form['checkbox'] = array(
                '#type' => 'checkbox',
                '#prefix' => "<div class='rowH'>",
                '#suffix' => "</div>",
                '#ajax' => array(
                  'callback' => 'checkbox_ajax',
                'wrapper' => 'checkbox_ajax-wrapper'
                ),
                  ); 
    return $form;
}
```

I need to change prefix class

```
function checkbox_ajax($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['checkbox']['#prefix'] = "<div class='rowHB'>";

  return $form['checkbox'];  

}
```

if someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function checkbox1($form, &form_state) {
```

and:

```
function checkbox_ajax($form, $form_state) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkbox1($form_state) {
    $form['checkbox'] = array(
                '#type' => 'checkbox',
                '#prefix' => (isset($form_state['values']['checkbox']) && $form_state['values']['checkbox'] ) ? "<div class='rowHB'>" : "<div class='rowH'>", //CHANGE HERE
                '#suffix' => "</div>",
                '#ajax' => array(
                  'callback' => 'checkbox_ajax',
                'wrapper' => 'checkbox_ajax-wrapper'
                ),
                  ); 
    return $form;
}
```

if $form['checkbox'] is checked than $form_state['values']['checkbox'] will equal to 1 thus ($form_state['values']['checkbox']) will equal to true.

I think this should work, but didn't test yet.